# Javascript console log clearing itself after if statement evaluates to false

Tags: javascript, if-statement, logging, console

I have the following simple code from an exercise in Modern Javascript used to calculate a sphere's volume, it contains a part which checks to make sure that a value has been entered for radius.

- I put in a negative number to test the function, and it works, but I
  was interested in what would be displayed in the console, so I checked.  I end up
  seeing an error flash in the log and then disappear - too quick to read.
- Is this just what occurs when an if statement evaluates to false? 
  Why is this error displaying and then being cleared almost
  immediately?  I'm aware I could use another way to debug this (a.k.a. using console.log or logging the problem by some other means), I'm just interested as to why this error disappears.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Volume of a Sphere Calculator</title>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- sphere.html -->
    <form action="" method="post" id="theForm">
        <fieldset>
            <p>Use this form to calculate the volume of a sphere.</p>
            <div>
                <label for="radius">Radius</label>
                <input type="text" name="radius" id="radius" required></div>
            <div>
                <label for="volume">Volume</label>
                <input type="text" name="volume" id="volume"></div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Calculate" id="submit"></div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <script src="js/sphere.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function calculate() {
    'use strict';

    var volume;
    var radius = document.getElementById('radius');

    if (radius && (radius.value > 0)){

        volume = (4/3) * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius.value, 3);

    }
    volume = volume.toFixed(4);

    document.getElementById('volume').value = volume;

    return false;
}

function init() {
    'use strict';
    var theForm = document.getElementById('theForm');
    theForm.onsubmit = calculate;
}

window.onload = init;
```

Comment: if `radius.value <= 0`, then `volume` is `undefined`. `undefined` does not have a method `toFixed`, so it will throw an error. Since this is in the `onsubmit` handler, it never reaches the `return false` line, which prevents the default action of a form submission which is to perform a post on the current page. **TLDR**: Initialize `volume` to `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `undefined` does not have a method `toFixed`, which throws an error, preventing `Calculate` from ever reaching `return false;`

Since that line is never reached, the form submits, which (generally speaking) posts the form to the same page.

When the page reloads, the console is reset (I believe this depends on the specific browser).

To fix this, initialize `volume` to `0`.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is in fact true - you're assuming that false not being returned is causing the problem, but even if you append an else statement which returns false and skips the toFixed method you still see the flash and disappearance of an error.

Comment: @mcabrams Incorrect, see here: http://jsbin.com/axovay/1/  `else return false` is stopping the form from submitting. But since you seem to think it's a good idea to downvote people who are trying to help you, that's all the help you'll get from me.

Comment: I actually never downvoted you - as you can see I only have 20 rep, and, as far as I can tell, the ability to downvote only becomes unlocked at 125 rep - sorry that somebody downvoted you.  

Anyways, I'm not sure what the difference was when I tried doing that, thanks for your help though!

Comment: Fair enough, glad I could help.

Answer (score 6):

Because this is the top Google match for my problem of console.log output appearing and quickly disappearing, this happened to me because I either had an empty set of label tags out of place or a form with no action. Deleting those tags caused JavaScript and console.log() to work like it was supposed to.

Comment: Form tag was causing my issue too. I forgot that forms by default refresh the page after submit.

Comment: If the page refresh is the issue, the "Preserve log" can also be used

Comment: Right, yes, removing the form tag altogether (using jsx) helped, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Adding another solution as a Google search for "javascript log disappearing" brought me here.

Page refreshing/navigation was the problem.

Selecting "Preserve log" in the console settings as per mateuszb's comment solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use el.preventDefault();  in your callback function

Comment: Sometimes in general, the case is that the form submits and that's why the page refreshes and everything including the console log is cleared. So, to remain on page even in case of errors, one may use the following snippet:
function calculate(e) {
 e.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission.
 // rest of the code
}